# Extracting data by row number after a set condition

Tags: r, row, row-number

I have a data.frame that is imported from an excel file which has been used with an irregular structure to make it visually appealing but the data is not usable. It is in repeated blocks of grouped data, with the word "Week" marking a new entry.
I am creating a code to extract the relevant data. Here is a **mwe**

```
df = data.frame(x1 = c("Week", "Day", "Exercise", NA, NA, "Walk","Week", "Day", "Exercise", NA, NA, "Run"),
                x2 = c("1", "1",NA, "Advice", NA,NA,"1", "2",NA, "Advice", NA,NA) )
df
                x1     x2
1      Week      1
2       Day      1
3  Exercise   <NA>
4      <NA> Advice
5      <NA>   <NA>
6      Walk   <NA>
7      Week      1
8       Day      2
9  Exercise   <NA>
10     <NA> Advice
11     <NA>   <NA>
12      Run   <NA>
```

First I want to create avariable of "Week" and "Day" which will apply to the corresponding entry:

```
df = df%>%
  mutate(Week = case_when(x1 == "Week" ~ x2 ),
         Day =  case_when(x1 == "Day" ~ x2))%>%
  fill(c(Week, Day), .direction= "downup") # fill missing values (NA) with the preceding present value 

df
         x1     x2 Week Day
1      Week      1    1   1
2       Day      1    1   1
3  Exercise   <NA>    1   1
4      <NA> Advice    1   1
5      <NA>   <NA>    1   1
6      Walk   <NA>    1   1
7      Week      1    1   1
8       Day      2    1   2
9  Exercise   <NA>    1   2
10     <NA> Advice    1   2
11     <NA>   <NA>    1   2
12      Run   <NA>    1   2
```

Then I want to extract the Exercise that was done, which **is always 3 rows below the word "Exercise"** in `x1`.

The result should look like this

```
x1       x2     Week  Day   Exercise
   <fct>    <fct>  <fct> <fct> <fct>   
 1 Week     1      1     1     Walk    
 2 Day      1      1     1     Walk    
 3 Exercise NA     1     1     Walk    
 4 NA       Advice 1     1     Walk    
 5 NA       NA     1     1     Walk    
 6 Walk     NA     1     1     Walk    
 7 Week     1      1     1     Walk    
 8 Day      2      1     2     Run     
 9 Exercise NA     1     2     Run     
10 NA       Advice 1     2     Run     
11 NA       NA     1     2     Run     
12 Run      NA     1     2     Run
```

How an I specify the row number after a condition and extract the data from a specified column in that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `dplyr` solutions and after searching found the function `nth`:

```
df =df%>%
  group_by(Week, Day)%>%
  mutate(Exercise = nth(x1,(which(str_detect(x1, "Exercise"))+3)))
```

`which` numbers the row where `str_detect` finds "Exercise". +3 to move on 3
`nth` can be used to find the data in that row number in `x1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `dplyr` replacing `NA` with `0`, then using `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))) %>% 
  mutate(Day = cumsum(x1=="Week")) %>% 
  group_by(Day) %>%
  mutate(Exercise = last(x1))
```

Output:

```
   x1       x2       Day Exercise
   <chr>    <chr>  <int> <chr>   
 1 Week     1          1 Walk    
 2 Day      1          1 Walk    
 3 Exercise 0          1 Walk    
 4 0        Advice     1 Walk    
 5 0        0          1 Walk    
 6 Walk     0          1 Walk    
 7 Week     1          2 Run     
 8 Day      2          2 Run     
 9 Exercise 0          2 Run     
10 0        Advice     2 Run     
11 0        0          2 Run     
12 Run      0          2 Run
```